# Making regex case-insensitive

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, regular-expressions

I have created some lines of code for an email handler that will scrape my emails for a particular string (STA0123).

Code:

```
  // Find STA No. (in email body)
  Opportunity Opp = [SELECT id, STA_No__c Opportunity WHERE Id = :matcher.group(0)];
  String staNo = email.plainTextBody;
  Pattern staPattern = Pattern.compile('STA[0-9]{4}');
  Matcher matcherSta = staPattern.matcher(staNo);
  if (matcherSta.find())
    Opp.STA_No__c = matcherSta.group(0);
```

This works as expected but only with the first part of the string in capitals, `STA0123` matches the pattern but `sta0123` does not.

Comment: Have you tried something like `Pattern.compile('[s|S]{1}[t|T]{1}[a|A]{1}[0-9]{4}');`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use JAVA-like CASE_INSENSITIVE pattern `(?i)`

Something like this:

```
Pattern staPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)STA[0-9]{4}');
```

Comment: I saw that pattern from java, wasn't sure whether it's applicable to APEX :). Good catch!

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can re-apply case sensitivity within the expression using `(?-i)`. Any part of the expression to the right of `(?i)` will be case insensitive and anything to the right of `(?-i)` will be case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

To make it case insensitive, you can just modify your pattern as follows

```
   Pattern staPattern = Pattern.compile('[Ss][Tt][Aa][0-9]{4}');
```

This can be long winded if you have a long pattern, so then you use the ignore case modifier

```
 Pattern staPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)sta[0-9]{4}');
```

Comment: Apologies I thought it was my answer I'm editing :)... Reverting back!

Answer (score 2):

`Pattern.compile('[s|S]{1}[t|T]{1}[a|A]{1}[0-9]{4}');` should do the trick. Basically what this does is:

Find the letter "S" either lower or upper case (only 1), followed by the same rule for the letter "T" and "A", then followed by any digit (4 times).

I've tested this and it worked for all possible combinations:

```
STA1234
sTa1234
sta1234
...
```