# Regex: Make Dot Match Newline?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string, pattern, matcher

I use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test my regular expressions, when I need them. I am having a bit of trouble crafting an expression that will work for me. For reference, I am trying to match [multiple substrings in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order). My problem, however, is that I cannot get the dot (`.`) character to match newline characters.

I learned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49516/making-regex-case-insensitive) that you can merge in options at the beginning of an expression using `(?[options])`, so I assumed `(?m)` would help me here. However, it does not seem to work:

```apex
Pattern keyword = Pattern.compile('(?mi)(?=.*\\bjack\\b)(?=.*\\bjill\\b)');
system.debug(keyword.pattern()); //(?mi)(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjill\b)

system.assert(keyword.matcher('jack n jill').find(); // works
system.assert(keyword.matcher('jill n jack').find(); // works
system.assert(keyword.matcher('Jack n Jill').find(); // works
system.assert(keyword.matcher('jack \n jill').find(); // fail
```

However, it seems to me that this approach [should work](http://rubular.com/r/I9bEgNuuRt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different languages use different flags to control inline behavior. I gather that Ruby uses `m` to make dot match newline, but in Apex (and most other languages too, I think) you would want to use the `s` modifier flag to get this behavior.

Many languages use `m` to mean multi-line: The ^ and $ anchors now match at the beginning/end of each line respectively, instead of beginning/end of the entire string.
and `s` to mean single-line: The dot (.) metacharacter will with this flag enabled also match new lines.

Btw, my personal favorite Regex tester is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Interesting. Just curious, do you have a reference to back this up? That would make this answer more helpful for me, and more credible too!

Comment: I just added a link to the online regex tester that I use, which includes descriptions of all modifier flags

Comment: Wow, I'd give you another +1 just for the link if I could. Amazing tool. Already bookmarked.

Comment: Note: You'll want to read the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Java documentation, upon which Apex Code runs under. `s` enables the DOTALL flag (which allows . to match newline characters), while `m` only alters the effect of ^ and $ at the beginning/end of the line.