# Substring Error - Ending Position Out Of Bounds

Tags: apex, trigger, case, string

I am trying to copy a `Rich Text Field (32k)` into multiple `Rich Text Field (2k)`. I get this error:

> System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds:2000.

**Code**

```
trigger UpdateCaseResponse on Case (before update) {
    for(Case c: trigger.new ){
        if (c.Response__c != null)        
        if(c.Response__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Response__c )

        try{
            c.Response_Part1__c = c.Response__c.substring(0,2000);
            c.Response_Part2__c = c.Response__c.substring(2001,4000);
        }       
        catch (System.NullPointerException e) {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is that your string may be actually shorter than 2k. That's why it says out of bounds. Check total length of string first, and then use 2k or total length, whatever is longer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to using substring, you can also use Pattern/Matcher:

```
SObjectField[] fields = new SObjectField[] {  // List your fields...
    Case.Response_Part1__c, Case.Response_Part2__c,
    Case.Response_Part3__c, Case.Response_Part4__c // ...
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?s).{1,2000}');  // Read up to 2k at a time

for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Response__c == null || record.Response__c == Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).Response__c) {
        continue;
    }
    Matcher m = p.matcher(c.Response__c);
    for(Integer fieldToUse = 0; fieldToUse < fields.size() && m.find(); fieldToUse++) {
        record.put(fields[fieldToUse], m.group(0));
    }
}
```

This avoids substring exceptions and a particularly nasty set of if statements.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Works with strings up to 1,000,000 characters.

Comment: I think you need to [match newline characters](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114303/regex-make-dot-match-newline). So `(?s).{1,2000}`

Comment: @AdrianLarson I knew I forgot something.

Comment: It would be interesting to profile the performance differences (between our answers). I'm having a hard time of it currently but may revisit later.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Substring: about 0.01ms per 2k string within the larger string, and 0.02ms per 2k string with regexp. Tested by building a million character string, and processing it 100 times, which was ~500ms vs ~1000ms over several runs. While substring is twice as fast, either method should be acceptable in the context of a trigger, since even 32k strings * 200 is only 6.4 million characters compared to my test of 100,000,000 characters.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, thanks a lot for your answer, i just tested your code, works great but strange 'pan="1" rowspan="1" class="noWrap">' appear at the start of part2 field and 'llpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 1000px;">' at the start of 4th field, can you let me know how to avoid this...

Comment: @sfdcfox - Just a quick question, can you tell me how to clear the values of unused fields after the update - if 10k (5 2k fields in this case) is updated to 4k, i want only 2 fields (1st and 2nd) to be used, but it still shows the old data i,e. 10k (2k in 3rd, 4th and 5th field as well), how to clear these fields, appreciate your help, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Khyber Just clear all the fields beforehand (`for(sobject field: fields) { record.put(field, null); }`), probably right before the `for(integer fieldToUse = 0...` part.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Hi, thanks for your response, yeah just tried the same earlier but gives an error 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Case].put(SObject, NULL)' so wondering am i missing something simple here...

Comment: @Khyber Sorry, that should have been `for(sobjectfield field: fields) ...`

Comment: @sfdcfox - Yup, that did the trick, also just tried to mimick the 'fieldToUse' for loop, both ways work, i already have my test class @100%,...;-)so i am good to go...ty once again, i appreciate it!!!

Comment: @Khyber Great! Glad I could be of assistance. Enjoy the rest of your weekend!

Answer (score 8):

Note that you do not need to skip an index between substrings. Your current pattern actually loses data.  When you do `substring(2001, 4000)`, you start at character `#2002`. When you do `substring(0, 2000)`, you stop at character `#2000` (whose index was `1999`). So you lose character `#2001` whose index is `2000`.

This can be demonstrated simply:

```
String text = '1234567890';
system.assertEquals('12345', text.substring(0, 5);
system.assertEquals('7890', text.substring(6, 10);
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) (emphasis mine):

> - **substring(startIndex, endIndex)**
>     Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified zero-based startIndex and *extends to the character at endIndex - 1*.

If instead the substring extended to `endIndex`, you would need to do `substring(0, 1999)`, etc.

---

**Solution**

You need to split the data out into up to 16 chunks. To make it scalable, I would do something like the following in an `Apex Class` and then call it from your trigger.

```
public with sharing class CaseServices
{
    static final List<SObjectField> responseChunkFields = new List<SObjectField>
    {
        Case.Response_Part1__c, Case.Response_Part2__c,
        Case.Response_Part3__c, Case.Response_Part4__c,
        Case.Response_Part5__c, Case.Response_Part6__c,
        Case.Response_Part7__c, Case.Response_Part8__c,
        Case.Response_Part9__c, Case.Response_Part10__c,
        Case.Response_Part11__c, Case.Response_Part12__c,
        Case.Response_Part13__c, Case.Response_Part14__c,
        Case.Response_Part15__c, Case.Response_Part16__c,
    };
    public static void chunkResponses(List<Case> records)
    {
        for (Case record : records) chunkResponse(record);
    }
    static void chunkResponse(Case record)
    {
        if (String.isBlank(record.Response__c)) return;
        Integer length = record.Response__c.length;
        Integer chunks = (Integer)(length/2000.0).round(RoundingMode.UP);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
        {
            Integer j = (i == chunks - 1) ? length : 2000*(i+1);
            String chunk = record.Response__c.substring(2000*i, j);
            record.put(responseChunkFields[i], chunk);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd cache the results from getChunks for performance reasons: `for(Integer i = 0, size = getChunks(record.Response__c); i < size; i++)`...

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that ending position isn't out of bounds, so you can't just use 2000*(i+1).

Comment: Doesn't caching it just increase heap? Only calculates once I think. Will fix ending position out of bounds though, yes. -- Ah I see it now.

Comment: Yes, the heap would increase by about 4-8 bytes, I think, but you save on repeated division and rounding, which can add up. And, no, the loop condition has to execute the function every time, since it doesn't know that length won't change.

Comment: Hey Adrian, thanks a lot for your response, i just tested your code, same error 'Ending position out of bounds: 8000' on line 20.

Comment: @Khyber Sorry, should compare to `chunks - 1`. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason :-**

The length of string is less than 2000 which caused an error.

**Resolution:-**

Please use length() function of String class to solve the issue. Please use the below code:-

```
trigger UpdateCaseResponse on Case (before update) {        
    for(Case c: trigger.new ){        
        Integer resLength =  c.Subject.length();        
        if (c.Response__c != null)        
        if(c.Response__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Response__c )            
        if( resLength <= 2000){
            c.Response_Part1__c = c.Response__c.substring(0,resLength);
        }                       
        else if( resLength > 2000 &&  resLength <= 4000 ){              
            c.Response_Part1__c = c.Response__c.substring(0,2000);
            c.Response_Part2__c = c.Response__c.substring(2001,resLength);
        }                               
    }  
}
```

Comment: Most try/catch code does more harm than good including in this case; suggest you remove that.

Comment: Also, that if statement would be a beast written that way. Lots of copy-pasting, and prone to simple mistakes.

Comment: Hey Shanu, thanks a lot for your response, i appreciate it, i just tried your code, by the time i was down to part 4 field, it was cumbersome.