# Apex Pattern, match everything (including new lines) between 2 passed parameters?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm trying to get a substring from a block of text that can contain new lines. Whats the regex needed to capture everything including newlines between 2 strings thats are passed in?

The regex below works in a similar function that doesn't need to include new lines.

```
private static String getSubString(
    String text,
    String startString,
    String endString
  ) {
    List<String> matchList = new List<String>();
    String patternStart = Pattern.quote(startString);
    String patternEnd = Pattern.quote(endString);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStart + '(.*?)' + patternEnd);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    
    while (matcher.find()) {
      matchList.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    if (matchList.size() > 0) {
      return matchList[0];
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: I believe you are running into [this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/114303/2995)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you simply need to set the `single-line` flag (`s`) which will make dot match newline characters.

```
Pattern.compile('(?s)' + patternStart + '(.*?)' + 'patternEnd')
```